# Periodically updating OpenStreetMap tile server to keep it up to date?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, osm2pgsql

I have successfully built my tile server by following this link (https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/) and open layers for viewing the tiles.

How do I keep automate the process of updating my tile server periodically from OpenStreetMap server?

I couldn't find any tutorial related to the same.

I read that Mapnik has tools that pulls data from the OpenStreetMap periodically but could not figure out how to get it up and running. 
I also tried to do it using the updating section of (https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/) but it wasn't helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be found at [How do I periodically update my tile server and keep it up to date](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/66220/how-do-i-periodically-update-my-tile-server-and-keep-it-up-to-date) in the OpenStreetMap Help.